# electron: How to screenshot in every 5 minutes then send it to server using http post

Tags: javascript, electron

I need some easy to make cross platform apps. So i think  electron is a way to go since im already familiar with html, css and javascript.

What node modules that i need to do this? I read the electron docs and it only says about screen recording but not screenshot.

And what i need to do for encoding the image to png then send it to server as a file with http post?

The app im making is a simple anti cheat solution.

Comment: Do you want to take a screenshot of the whole display of the computer, or just of the electron application window?

Comment: @Nisala the whole screen

Comment: This might be what you're looking for? It looks like all electron can do is take a screen recording/"video stream" of the display, as you found from your research, but then you can take an image from that video stream and save that as an image, thus making a screenshot. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/280/creating-screenshots-of-your-app-or-the-screen-in-electron-framework

Comment: @Nisala okay, thanks for your help